# Alkynes on ozonolysis

Tags: organic-chemistry

What are the products formed on ozonolysis of 1-hexyne followed by hydrolysis?

I am not getting whether Pentanal is formed or pentanoic acid is formed and sub products

Answer (score 1):

According to [libretexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Alkenes/Reactivity_of_Alkenes/Ozonolysis) the final product of ozonolysis of alkene will depend on what was along with ozone.

If we are using zinc along with ozone then we would get aldehyde.

If we are using Hydrogen peroxide along with ozone then we would get carboxylic acid.

In ozonolysis of alkynes we would get diketone or anhydride which could react further in presence of water *(water would react with ozone to give hydrogen peroxide)* to give two carboxylic acids.

In case of alkyne ozonolysis we would get no aldehyde.

In your example of ozonolysis of 1-hexyne we would get pentanoic acid and formic acid after cleavage of triple bond. Formic acid will get further oxidised to give carbon dioxide.

Source : [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozonolysis) [Youtube](https://youtu.be/GgL9Xv2Pt2w?si=qZJ0LEH3HitrE5zJ)

Comment: Dimethyl sulfide is the more frequently used work up rather than zinc

Comment: @Waylander Yes you are right but zinc is more easily available and easier to remember from academics point of view. In my textbook we don't have dimethyl sulfide.

Comment: Get a better textbook. DMS is what is actually used by chemists who run ozonolysis

Comment: 1-hexyne is not symmetric so we get two different products. Can you name the other product(s)?